# Looking for some good alternatives to SP Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, lookup-column

I have a SharePoint list where one of the columns is a lookup to a different list. This works fine as long as the other list does not crosses its 5000 item limit. Also, a dropdown list with ~5000 items does not looks workable also. I am looking for alternatives to this normal lookup method? Any custom CSOM solution will also work for me. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Every list's view SharePoint has only threshold of 5000 items(not only the lookup).
This link describe your problem and the solutions that could be used

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

and this link may be help you to handle the lookup list 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C

However,I know this information but I haven't faced this problem.
Good luck